# Finding shape in list of 2d points

Tags: python, algorithm, opencv, 2d, homography

I have a shape which is made from 6 2d-coordinates and a list of 6 found 2d-coordinates in a 2d-picture which is uncalibrated.
What I need, is a way to find out, which found point from the image is which of the original shape.

My current approach after reading through several threads:

```
M, mask = cv2.findHomography(fixpts, dstpts, cv2.RANSAC, 2.0)
if all(p == 1 for p in mask):
    return M, pe
```

I am trying to find all possible permutations of the 6 image points and use the openCV function findHomography where fixpts is a list of the known coordinates and dstpts the found coordinates.
For every permutation I now check if the result of the findHomography call results in only inliers. If that's the case, I'll use the current permutation to assign the points to each other.

This is by far not an elegant and additionally a very slow way to do this so I'd love to hear of an elegant solution to this problem.

Comment: is there always one true 1:1 correspondence and no additional points?

Comment: Yes, I ignore cases in which the point count doesn't match.

Comment: I remember a case from virtual reality course: You have some markers and want to match them to your marker model. Afair it was done with singular value decomposition. Maybe this paper is exactly what you need: http://www.hpl.hp.com/techreports/97/HPL-97-96.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The RANSAC-algorithm of `cv2.findHomography` takes random subsets of 4 point-pairs to compute perspective transformations and takes the best fit (see [doc](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html?highlight=findhomography#findhomography))

This is something one can do directly in a more efficient way: generate all subsets of 4 source points and all tuples of 4 different target points and compute the homography matrix with the standard algorithm. Choose the one with the best match. (If the RANSAC-version of `cv2.findHomography` is smart enough to check each subset only once this could give a speed up of factor 2, otherwise maybe even more.)

If your points are exact enough you could restrict your search to the first 4 source points (generate only 1 subset) and try to match them with all tuples of 4 different target points. This would give another speed up of factor 15.

A further speed up could be gained by restricting the search using the perspective invariant of inside vs on the outer contour and also the order of points on the outer contour. One can use the convex hulls of the 6 source and target points. If e.g. all source points are on the convex hull (then also all 6 target points should be on their convex hull) then one only needs to check six correspondences (the first correspondence determines the other correspondences by going along the outer contour in the same orientation). This approach is, however, harder to implement because of the different cases (3,4,5 or 6 points on the outer contour) and also because of "exactness" problems if e.g. one source point is close to the outer contour but not part of the convex hull and the corresponding target points is on the convex hull.